# Discord.py - Is there a way to use *args or a parameter with multiple words without it being the last parameter?

Tags: python, bots, discord, args

Here is the current command:

```
`async def namemembers(self, ctx, members, name, *args):`
```

This works fine enough, but I would like to add more parameters after *args, or if there is another way to use the `name` parameter to allow spaces and multiple words. If I try to do something like:

```
`async def namemembers(self, ctx, members, name, *args, worlds):`
```

To define the world, it always says that `world` is a required argument that is missing. "Worlds" are split by a `/` but it still considers the `/` as part of the *args. Ideally I would have a command like this:

```
`async def nameM(self, ctx, name, *, worlds):`
```

Which would allow me to use the `name` parameter with many words. Since currently using it this way "allows" me to input multiple words, but the bot sends back only the first word anyway.

Hopefully my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

No. `*args` is ambiguous because it takes any number of arguments, so there would be no way for Python to know when you're done with `*args` and onto `worlds`.

Python doesn't know and won't allow you to force `worlds` to be a kwarg only.

As a rule of thumb, you write methods with arguments in the following order:

```py
def main(arg1, arg2, ..., *args, *kwargs):
    pass
```

Comment: is there another way to use another parameter to allow multiple words?

Comment: a list? @Brenda